# How do I specify my own LookupStrategy implementation for the grails spring security ACL plugin?

Tags: grails, spring-security, nosql, acl, grails-plugin

I'd like to use the Spring Security ACL plugin in my Grails 2.0.4 application. However, my app does not use JDBC or a SQL database. (We're using MongoDB).

The GormAclLookupStrategy implementation in that plugin uses HQL, which is not supported by MongoDB-Gorm, so I suppose I need to create an alternate implementation of that class.

My question is, once I have that alternate implementation, how do I configure the bean to use it? From my examination of the plugin code, it looks to me like the plugin will override my attempt to configure it view the usual conf mechanism. Or am I reading it wrong?

Can someone give me a clue? , @BurtBeckwith are you out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you register a bean in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` with the same name as one registered by Grails or a plugin, yours takes precedence. This true for any bean, not just this one. So you would do something like this:

```
import com.mycompany.myapp.MyAclLookupStrategy

beans = {
   aclLookupStrategy(MyAclLookupStrategy) {
      // properties, bean refs, etc.
   }
}
```